# Jquery Ajax post method getting 404 error, GET works fine (the file exists). Server Files exist in Node server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a file on the backend: /assets/frontEndJSON/allrequests.json. ajax's 'GET' works file to populate the page with the data. However after I manipulate the data on the front end, click a "submit type" button to call ajax's 'POST' I am getting a 404 error.

The files are stored on a Node.js server.

```
var back = JSON.stringify(q.items, null, 2)
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/assets/frontEndJSON/allrequests.json',
              data: back,
              dataType: 'json'
            })
```

I want the data that is being manipulated to be (in my case) deleted from the file in the node server.

Backend Code:

```
var dirBuf = Buffer.from('public/assets/jsonfiles')
fs.readdir(dirBuf, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  else {
    var all = [];
    //files
      files.forEach(function(filename) {
      var txt = fs.readFileSync('public/assets/jsonfiles/' + filename);
      var filecontents = JSON.parse(txt)
      all = (all.concat(filecontents));
    })
    var back = JSON.stringify(all, null, 2)
    /* UNCOMMENT TO CREATE FRONT END FILE */
  //  fs.writeFileSync('public/assets/frontEndJSON/allrequests.json', back)
  }
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
});
```

Comment: A json file is not a script file.  It's not going to process your request for changes.  You have to write an endpoint to actually manipulate the file, outside of a simple retrieval.

Comment: @Taplar Would that script file be written in php (for example)?

Comment: It could be, sure. Or it could be written for node, or any other server side scripting language.

Comment: @Taplar I am assuming Javascript could also be used to avoid a language I'm not familiar with. Any resources you could point me to to help me get started on such a file/route?

Comment: Using javascript to do it would require you to use node, afaik.  That's the path you'd take to make javascript run on the server.